# How to translate this old XNA code to XNA 4.0 code?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, xna-3.0

This old code doesn't work in XNA 4.0. What must be changed so that the code works in XNA 4.0?

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend,SpriteSortMode.Immediate,SaveStateMode.None,Matrix.Identity);
  graphics.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MagFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
  graphics.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MinFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
  graphics.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MipFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
spriteBatch.End();
```

I get the following error messages:

> 'SpriteBlendMode' does not exist in the current context
>   'SaveStateMode' does not exist in the current context 
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SamplerState' does not contain a
>   definition for 'MagFilter' and no extension method 'MagFilter'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SamplerState' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SamplerState' does not contain a
>   definition for 'MinFilter' and no extension method 'MinFilter'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SamplerState' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SamplerState' does not contain a
>   definition for 'MipFilter' and no extension method 'MipFilter'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SamplerState' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not really help. Does it compile? Does it give error messages, and if so what? Does it run without error and respond unexpectedly?

Comment: I added the error messages.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a resource that will show you how to solve these problems:

http://www.nelxon.com/blog/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet/

These are all very common problems related to upgrading old XNA code to 4.0

Comment: I tried to change the code, but I don't know how to change MagFilter, MinFilter and Mipfilter. What should I change in those 3 lines?

Comment: Sadly, the example is given out of context for this particular issue - presumably in draw code, which seems to be when SamplerStates[0] is null or read only.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you have to look out for in bringing your code up to date with the 4.0 version of the XNA Framework:

- SpriteBatch.Begin syntax is slightly different
- SamplerState.Mag, .Mip, and .Min properties have all been [combined into the .Filter property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/02/state-objects-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)
- SpriteBlendMode is now [replaced with BlendState objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)

Also, one more thing (which caught me as I was updating my code): It seems that something changed in-between versions 3.1 and 4.0 of the XNA framework that will make it so the SamplerStates collection and SamplerState objects are read-only after the graphics device is initialized. I found that creating my own SamplerState object (and modifying the properties there) worked:

```
SamplerState sState = new SamplerState();
sState.Filter = TextureFilter.Point;
BaseGame.Device.SamplerStates[0] = sState;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, Matrix);
spriteBatch.End();
```

In XNA 4.0 You cannot change sampler state without re-iniating the Graphics Device,
  so in your games Initialize() Method, You need to add   `graphics.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].Filter = TextureFilter.Point;`

To the best of my knowledge, that should be what you are looking for!

Comment: It doesn't work. I get this error message and I don't know how to fix it: Cannot change read-only SamplerState. State objects become read-only the first time they are bound to a GraphicsDevice. To change property values, create a new SamplerState instance.

Comment: In XNA 4.0 You cannot change the sampler state, withoit reinitiating the Graphics Device, So, Add the  "graphics.graphicsDevice.samplerstates[0]..." part in your initialize method